# Oracle: Easy way to find names and/or number of child record tables

Tags: oracle, count, parent-child

Not really a question because this works for me but is there an easier and more direct way to get the number of child records for any given table? Or get a list of those child records? Here's what I'm doing (obviously this would be dynamic and in a cursor loop):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number-of-child-records
  FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
 WHERE     CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%SOMETABLENAME%'
       AND SUBSTR (CONSTRAINT_NAME, 1, 4) = 'FK1_'
       AND TABLE_NAME <> 'SOMETABLENAME';
```

or

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
 WHERE     CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%SOMETABLENAME%'
       AND SUBSTR (CONSTRAINT_NAME, 1, 4) = 'FK1_'
       AND TABLE_NAME <> 'SOMETABLENAME';
```

FYI: Why I'm doing this:

ORACLE has a lot of ALL_whatever table info tables but none that list parents or child records directly and simply.

I have an automated program that needs to change a key value in one or many tables--depending on what it finds. It dumps out to a temp table, changes the value there, deletes the entry(s) in the actual table entry, then inserts the record(s) back from the temp table, then deletes records from the temp table.

The key value may exist in records with parent-child relations. So I need to deal with child records first on the delete and then parent records first on the insert. I had been recording the number of child records for each table in a notation table as I ran into new tables to deal with. So the cursor to remove (temporarily) is sorted by the number-of-child-records ASC then DESC insert back.

Comment: So what is the problem? Show us sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Allen, I think you are asking first how to find all *tables* that are related to a particular *parent* table, as defined by properly defined foreign keys, and using that to programatically spin through the "tree" of related tables to allow the ability to change key fields.  If so, edit your question to clarify this, or if not true, you need to not mention child _records_ for a given table as you are skipping a step.  

As you probably are stuck with the current design, I won't suggest that using non-intelligent keys is the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: You seem to be searching "other" tables only. Why?

The simplest way to prevent your approach from working (whatever your need is) is with this example.

Only one table, and with only two columns, employee (PK) and manager (FK). If you delete the CEO, the emperor, whatever (the manager of all managers), then in principle you should delete all rows from the table, or otherwise deal with them.

How is ANY solution you come up with by excluding the current table going to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Create your own view and write hierarchical queries against it. Make sure to include all tables (a field in a table may be a FK referencing a PK **in the same table** - see my comment under your original post). In your hierarchical query you will need a `nocycle` somewhere.

Not sure why you identify foreign keys by their name and not by their type; see below.

You can use something like this to create the view:

```
select a.constraint_name   as f_key,
       a.owner             as f_owner,
       a.table_name        as f_table,
       a.r_constraint_name as p_key,
       a.r_owner           as p_owner,
       b.table_name        as p_table
from   all_constraints a inner join all_constraints b
                         on a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
where  a.constraint_type = 'R';
```

Here is part of the output on my database. (I cheated, I ran it against `user_constraints` - my schema name is `INTRO`).

```
F_KEY              F_OWNER    F_TABLE         P_KEY           P_OWNER    P_TABLE
------------------ ---------- --------------- --------------- ---------- ------------
REG_COURSEDATE_FK  INTRO      REGISTRATIONS   OFFERINGS_PK    INTRO      OFFERINGS
OFF_COURSE_FK      INTRO      OFFERINGS       COURSES_PK      INTRO      COURSES
EMP_DEP_FK         INTRO      EMPLOYEES       DEPARTMENTS_PK  INTRO      DEPARTMENTS
HIST_DEP_FK        INTRO      HISTORY         DEPARTMENTS_PK  INTRO      DEPARTMENTS
OFF_TRAINER_FK     INTRO      OFFERINGS       EMPLOYEES_PK    INTRO      EMPLOYEES
EMP_MGR_FK         INTRO      EMPLOYEES       EMPLOYEES_PK    INTRO      EMPLOYEES
REG_ATT_FK         INTRO      REGISTRATIONS   EMPLOYEES_PK    INTRO      EMPLOYEES
HIST_EMP_FK        INTRO      HISTORY         EMPLOYEES_PK    INTRO      EMPLOYEES
DEP_MGR_FK         INTRO      DEPARTMENTS     EMPLOYEES_PK    INTRO      EMPLOYEES
```

Notice the EMP_MGR_FK foreign key, which points back to the same table.

**Example**:

Suppose you created this view and called it `related_columns`. Then you can run a query like below:

```
select *
from   related_columns
start with f_table = 'EMPLOYEES'
connect by nocycle prior p_key = f_key;


F_KEY              F_OWNER    F_TABLE         P_KEY           P_OWNER    P_TABLE
------------------ ---------- --------------- --------------- ---------- ------------
EMP_DEP_FK         INTRO      EMPLOYEES       DEPARTMENTS_PK  INTRO      DEPARTMENTS
EMP_MGR_FK         INTRO      EMPLOYEES       EMPLOYEES_PK    INTRO      EMPLOYEES
```